# Count After Skip MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54368d9125c3dc7c1f43295f"),
    "nome" : "John",
    "eta" : 30,
    "data" : ISODate("2014-10-09T10:30:00.000Z")
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54368d9c25c3dc7c1f432960"),
    "nome" : "Paul",
    "eta" : 31
}
```

And I do this Query

```
db.coll.find({eta:{$gt:30}})
```

My result is one Document (Paul)

```
db.coll.find({eta:{$gt:30}}).count() //1
```

If i do

```
db.coll.find({eta:{$gt:30}}).skip(1)
```

I haven't Result,and it's ok.
But If i do this

```
db.coll.find({eta:{$gt:30}}).skip(1).count()
```

my Result is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for [`count()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#cursor.count):

> By default, the count() method ignores the effects of the cursor.skip() and cursor.limit(). Set applySkipLimit to true to consider the effect of these methods.

So you can supply an optional parameter named `applySkipLimit` to count(), if you want the effect of skip() to be considered, like this:

```js
db.coll.find({eta:{$gt:30}}).skip(1).count({applySkipLimit:1});
```

or simply

```js
db.coll.find({eta:{$gt:30}}).skip(1).count(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.size/#cursor.size) instead of `count` as it includes the effects of any `skip` and `limit` calls on the cursor:

```js
db.coll.find({eta:{$gt:30}}).skip(1).size()
```

Comment: thanks. But with `db.coll.find({eta:{$gt:30}})` I get cursor right?

Comment: Right, and `skip` and `size` are both cursor methods.  I might be missing what you're asking.